# Search.lookupFields() Method is return [0bject Object] instead of key value pair

Tags: javascript, json, object, netsuite, keyvaluepair

I have created the lookup search on customer record to get the particular field value.while putting obtained result in alert it showing as **[object,object]**. and i have converted result to string JSON stringfy method.

The alert showing the result like this :

```
{"custentity_cseg_customer_categ":[{"value":"6","text":"DTC"}]}
```

But want the values for the key "text" : Example : DTC in the above code

**Code:**

```
Suitescript 2.0 version:
    var customerCategoryFieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
                    type:'CUSTOMER' ,
                    id: 13,
                    columns: ['custentity_cseg_customer_categ']
                    });

                 alert("CustomerCategoryFieldLookUp:"+ JSON.stringify(customerCategoryFieldLookUp));
```

Comment: Have you tried `customerCategoryFieldLookUp.text` ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

```
alert( "CustomerCategoryFieldLookUp:"+ custentity_cseg_customer_categ[0].text);
```

Also the chrome devtools is your friend: press ctrl-shift-j and paste

```
x = {"custentity_cseg_customer_categ":[{"value":"6","text":"DTC"}]}
```

into the console now you can look at it and try exploring

Comment: The array index bit helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour of `search.lookupFields`. Check out the NS Help page titled *search.lookupFields(options)* for the documented API. Here is what Help says about the return value:

> **Returns:** `Object`
>
> - Returns select fields as an object with value and text properties.
> - Returns multiselect fields as an object with value:text pairs.
>
> For example, this method returns results in the following form:
>   
>   `{
>       internalid: 1234,
>       firstname: 'Joe',
>       my_select: [{
>           value: 1,
>           text: 'US Sub'
>       }],
>       my_multiselect: [{
>           value: 1,
>           text: 'US Sub'
>           },{
>           value: 2,
>           text: 'EU Sub'
>       }]
>   }`

In order to retrieve the value of a select or multiselect field, you need to use Array access:

```js
var customerCategoryFieldLookUp = search.lookupFields({
  type:'CUSTOMER' ,
  id: 13,
  columns: ['custentity_cseg_customer_categ']
});

alert("custentity_cseg_customer_categ:"+ customerCategoryFieldLookUp.custentity_cseg_customer_categ[0].value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try console.log(customerCategoryFieldLookUp) to check you object keys.
From what I see the object looks like

```
customerCategoryFieldLookUp {
   custentity_cseg_customer_categ :{
      value:6,
      text:"DTC"
   } 
}

Use
alert(customerCategoryFieldLookUp.custentity_cseg_customer_categ.text)
or
alert(customerCategoryFieldLookUp.custentity_cseg_customer_categ.value)
```